# Best way to parse single json string response

Tags: json, angular

I want to parse a json response like that :
{
    "code": "#546545"
}
from an angular 2 service. There are two ways that I know of:

1. Use an interface

   export interface ProductId{
     code: string;
   }
2. Since json is a string use: angular.fromJson(code)

I think 1 is an overkill for a single string along with what I know what is the best way for something so simple?

Comment: `observable` and `promise` have `.json()` method, so whatever `response` you get, you can get your `json` by that method.

Comment: Also, can you please clarify if its `angular` or `angularjs` ?

Comment: Bhavik Patel  AngularJs 2 could not find proper tag

Comment: there is no angularjs2 it is AngularJs , Angular, Angular4

Comment: There is no such thing as AngularJS 2. its either Angular 2 or AngularJs. Are you using Typescript?

Comment: Angular 2 then sorry

Comment: can you show us your service?

Comment: public getXCode() {
    return this.httpClient.API('GET', '/X/code');
  } 

I do not need an observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `JSON.parse(string)` or 
`angular.fromJson(string)`

which is just

```
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```

The interface would help you, I don't think it's an overkill. But you still need to parse the string anyway.